# How can I resize my QWidget in a QFormLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I tryed to resize my send button when it is in formlayout but isn't working 
How can i resize it and still leave it in the layout?

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.message_position = 0
        self.setWindowTitle("asd")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
        self.show()
        self.hbox = QFormLayout()
        self.initiateUI()
        self.window_width = self.width()
        self.window_height = self.height()
        self.hbox.addRow(self.send_button)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        print(self.hbox.geometry())
        #print(help(self.hbox))



    def send_text_UI(self):
        self.send_button = QPushButton("Send Message",self)
        self.send_button.resize(120,60)
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.update_content)
        self.send_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: lime;border-style:none")


    def initiateUI(self):
        #self.chat_box_UI()
        self.send_text_UI()
```

Comment: Calling `resize()` on widgets that are part of a layout manager is completely pointless: as the name suggests, layout managers ***manage*** the layout. If you want to set fixed sizes, use [`setFixedSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1). You should also avoid setting generic style sheets on containers, and use proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead.

Comment: Also note that while you say you tried to resize it "when it is in formlayout", you actually tried before adding it to the layout.

Comment: Besides what Passerby correctly points out, you should not call `show()` before completing the layout. Also, while creating functions that are only used once might seem a good choice of "code-elegance", it's almost always unnecessarily confusing, mostly because those functions will almost certainly be called just once (thus making their creation pointless). Finally, a widget size and its contents are correctly mapped only once they've been finally displayed on the OS window manager, so calling the `geometry()` of a widget or layout within the init is almost always useless.